# Couple doubts on ring theory from Artin Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have these two doubts, which are scattered only couple of pages away in Artin's book, so I am asking them in one post only:

1. Artin in his book algebra first shows that $(x^3-2)$ is kernel of substitution homomorphism $\Phi:\Bbb Q[x]\to\Bbb C$ given by $x\to\sqrt[3]2$ is $(x^3-2)$. Then claims that restriction $\Phi'$ of $\Phi$ to $\Bbb Z[x]$ has kernel that is also generated by $(x^3-2)$, and as a proof of that quotes this theorem: Let $f$ be a monic integer polynomial. If $f$ divides $g$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$, then $f$ divides $g$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

   > I can't see why restriction $\Phi':\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb C$ has ideal $(x^3-2)$ from above argument.
   >   Also, does above argument has to do something with "Let $f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$. If $f(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Q$, then it is reducible over $\Bbb Z$. " ?
2. They give this example: "We identify the ideals of quotient ring $R'=\Bbb C[t]/(t^2-1)$ using the canonical homomorphism $\pi:\Bbb C[t]\to R'$. The kernel of $\pi$ is the principal ideal $(t^2-1)$. Let $I$ be an ideal of $\Bbb C[t]$ that contains $t^2-1$. Then $I$ is principal, generated by monic polynomial $f$, and the fact that $t^2-1$ is in $I$ means that $f$ divides $t^2-1$. The monic divisors of $t^2-1$ are $1,t-1,t+1,t^2-1$. Therefore the ring $R'$ contains exactly four ideals. They are the principal ideals generated by the residues of the divisors of $t^2-1$."

   > Please explain what is meant by 'residues of the divisors'.

Comment: Elements in $R=K[t]/(t^2-1)$ are residues, because we have a factor ring.

Comment: The divisors of $t^2-1$ live in $\mathbb{C}[t]$; their residues (or reductions mod $(t^2 - 1)$) live in $\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2-1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD, any polynomial that admits $\sqrt[3]2$ as a root is divisible by $x^3 - 2$ (this is because $x^3 - 2$ is an irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by Eisenstein). It should be easy to see that any polynomial in the kernel of $\Phi'$ admits $\sqrt[3]{2}$ as a root.

Comment: How do we know that kernel has to be principal ideal? If it was $F[x]$ with field $F$, then we could be sure. Also, I can't quite get why any polynomial that admits $\sqrt[3]2$ as a root is divisible by $x^3−2$.

Comment: Certainly $x^3 - 2$ is in the kernel, so we have that $(x^3 - 2) \subset \ker(\Phi)$.

Comment: Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $p(\sqrt[3]{2}) = 0$. We have that $p(x) = q(x)(x^3 - 2)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (you should convince yourself of this --- using the division algorithm). If $q(x)$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we are done. If not, then $p(x) = a \cdot q(x)(x^3 - 2)$ where $a$ is the lcm of all the denominators of the coefficients of $q(x)$. Thus, $x^3 - 2$ divides $p(x)$.

Comment: Sorry for this late comment, but it will be $a\cdot p(x) = a \cdot q(x)(x^3 - 2)$ and not $p(x) = a \cdot q(x)(x^3 - 2)$, right? So, $p(x)$ need not be divisible in $\Bbb Z[x]$.